# PHP call zend call controller method in view file

Tags: php, zend-framework

My controller:

```
class CronController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function init(){
    }

    public function indexAction(){
        die();
    }

    public function reportAboutExpiringPaymentAction(){
    }
}
```

How can I call reportAboutExpiringPaymentAction() from `file.phtml`

Comment: But the question is why not to call that action in controller it self & pass return data to view ?

Answer (score 0):

The way that you need, doesn't work at all. Only way to call this function on a phtml is like this:
The URL is like: http://www.yoursite.com/cron/report-about-expiring-payment
And code is:

```
class CronController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function init(){
    }

    public function indexAction(){
        die();
    }

    public function reportAboutExpiringPaymentAction(){
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
        $this->render('file.phtml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View Actions helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) to call an action form the view. In your case `<?php echo $this->action('reportaboutexpiringpayment','cron',null); ?>` will execute the action